# Shortcut for rake db:migrate:down for ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, migration, rails-migrations

I want to know if there is a short way to do the migrations down equivalent to rake db:migrate (for the migrations up).
Instead of doing : rake db:migrate:up VERSION=1, rake db:migrate:up VERSION=2, ... we can do : rake db:migrate!
But for : rake db:migrate:down VERSION=10, rake db:migrate:down VERSION=..., rake db:migrate:down VERSION=1, is there a shortcut?

Tank you for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`rake db:migrate VERSION=0` will remove all migrations, if that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a premade task for doing what you want.  You can see all of the available rake tasks using rake -T.